# Detect Utf -8 Encode and decode it in header response

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, utf-8

I want to get that amount of Content-Disposition key after receiving the respos and in webClient.ResponseHeaders.
So that I can extract the file name from it.
Content-Disposition values available:

> "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''SC-FR-06-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%20%D8%AE%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AF.pdf; filename="SC-FR-06-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%20%D8%AE%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AF.pdf""

Now my first question is where does this UTF-8 encoder actually come from?
And the second question is I can not do anything if I decoder the UTF-8 encoder.

> %D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%20%D8%AE%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AF

I'm Using .Net3.5 and Wpf.

please guide me

Comment: Try [`system.web.httputility` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility?view=net-5.0). For instance, in PowerShell: `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode("%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%20%D8%AE%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AF")` returns `درخواست خرید`…

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ , but I use .net3.5 and inside wpf. Do you suggest a way for that?